# Blazor try's to reconnect on server while communicate with db login/logout

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am currently learning the Blazor Server platform on .Net 7.0, but I face this weird issue. Whenever I attempt to login or log-out, a message at the top of the page indicates, "Attempting to reconnect to the server: 1 of 8."

I have created multiple pages that involve interactions with the database, such as CRUD operations, and none of them replicate this particular problem.

When I open the console I notice this message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) WebSocket is not in the OPEN state
```

This is my CustomAuthenticationStateProvider:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
    {
        _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var userSessionStorageResult = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<UserSession>("UserSession");
            var userSession = userSessionStorageResult.Success ? userSessionStorageResult.Value : null;

            if (userSession == null)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
            }

            ClaimsPrincipal? claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userSession.UserName) ? userSession.UserName : string.Empty),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userSession.Role) ? userSession.Role : string.Empty),
            }, "CustomAuth"));

            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
        }
        catch
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
        }

    }

    public async Task UpdateAuthenticationState(UserSession userSession)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;
        if (userSession is not null)
        {
            await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("UserSession", userSession);
            claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userSession.UserName) ? userSession.UserName : string.Empty),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userSession.Role) ? userSession.Role : string.Empty),
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            await _sessionStorage.DeleteAsync("UserSession");
            claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
        }

        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
    }

}
```

And the login page:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <InputText id="username" @bind-Value="_loginModel.Username" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <InputText id="password" @bind-Value="_loginModel.Password" class="form-control" type="password" />
    </div>
    <small>@WrongPassword</small>
    <button @onclick="Authenticate" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</div>

@code {
    private LoginModel _loginModel = new LoginModel();
    string WrongPassword = String.Empty;

    private async Task Authenticate()
    {
        User? userAccount = await _userService.GetUserByUsername(_loginModel.Username);

        if (userAccount == null || userAccount.Password != _loginModel.Password)
        {
            return;
        }

        var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)authStateProvider;
        await customAuthStateProvider.UpdateAuthenticationState(new UserSession
            {
                UserName = userAccount.Username,
                Role = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAccount.Name) ? userAccount.Name.ToString() : string.Empty,
            });

        navManager.NavigateTo("/", true);

    }
}
```

Any feedback on what could be the issue and how can I resolve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: That error message means the SignalR comms are failing and the client and server cannot communicate.

Comment: But after 2-3 seconds it reconnects and redirects to the wanted page.